# How do you perform inheritance with abstract classes in dart? error : superclass SpanishData doesn't have a zero argument constructor

Tags: flutter, inheritance, dart, abstract

I'm trying to create an abstract class called SpanishData
And then I want to create another class called alphabet that extends Spanish data

I'm getting an error: the superclass SpanishData doesn't have a zero-argument constructor. How do I fix this?

Here is my code:

```
abstract class SpanishData{
  String englishWord;
  String spanishWord;
  String mp3;

  SpanishData(this.englishWord,this.spanishWord,this.mp3);

  void getList (){

  }



}


//the alphabet class

import '../SpanishDataAbstract.dart';


class Alphabet extends SpanishData{

  @override
  void getList(

      )


}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to refer to the properties of the `parent class` your `class` is extending. You can do this using the `super` keyword.

```
The super() method on a class constructor allows a subclass to pass arguments and execute the constructor of its superclass.
```

The code below works:

```
abstract class SpanishData{
  String englishWord;
  String spanishWord;
  String mp3;

  SpanishData(this.englishWord,this.spanishWord,this.mp3);

  void getList (){

  }
}


class Alphabet extends SpanishData{

  // create a constructor of the alphabet class and call the parent constructor
  Alphabet(String englishWord, String spanishWord, String mp3) : super(englishWord, spanishWord, mp3);

  @override
  void getList(){}
}
```